# Unable to start new fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, onclick

I have a tabbed layout using fragments, one of the tabs contains a button which should trigger another hidden fragment.

I have added the below on click code to the button but the fragment doesn't seem to start.

Any ideas?

my onClick code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestFragment.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_body, new TestFragment(), "frag screen");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your xml and TestFragment.java code

Comment: @Rami, just solved the problem, I was using the wrong container_body, I have a nav drawer and view pager, was using nav_drawer rather than view pager. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved the problem, Put your answer or close the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, I was using the wrong container_body, I have a nav drawer and view pager, was using nav drawer rather than view pager widget.